# Observable gets the wrong value when using the from operator with a promise after immediately updating that value in another promise

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, async-await, rxjs, capacitor

I have an `observable` that listens to route changes :) I also have a `promise` that clears my local storage and when it's done I immediately change the route but my `switchMap/switchMapTo` inside my route-change observable get the old value.. why does this happen?

I have tried many ways to solve this - I found two that work :) But I wish to **understand** why they worked. Could anyone please help? Is this something regarding `hot/cold observables` issues? Perhaps something with the `event loop`? I really don't know :)

```js
    this.storageService.clear().then((_) => {
      // this was successful!! And it was checked - user is deleted :)
      // now change the route and trigger the observable below :)
    });
    
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((e: Event): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      /*
        switchMap in here to get the user!
        Options 1 + 2 show that the user info exists!! 
        Although I know for sure that it was deleted.
        Option 3 + 4 work.
      */
    
      // 1) switchMapTo(from(this.storageService.getAsync<IUser>('user'))),
    
      // 2) switchMapTo(this.storageService.getAsync<IUser>('user')),
    
      // 3) switchMap(async (_) => {
      //      const y = await this.storageService.getAsync<IUser>('user');
      //      return y;
      //    }),
    
      // 4) switchMapTo(defer(() => this.storageService.getAsync<IUser>('user'))),
    );


    // Question edited for extra information - this is the getAsync function
    async getAsync<T>(key: string) {
        const result: GetResult = await Storage.get({ key });
        return JSON.parse(result.value) as T;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Eager vs Lazy Execution

This happens because promises are eager and observable are lazy. That is, an observable doesn't do anything until subscribed to whereas a promise is going to attempt to resolve itself from the moment it is defined.

Here's how I would write it in order to resolve this issue in the most straightforward manner:

```ts
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((e: Event): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
  switchMap(_ => this.storageService.getAsync<IUser>('user'))
);
```

**Update:**

Of course, not only asynchronous code (like promises and observables) can have eager/lazy evaluation semantics. Regular synchronous code can have the same issues. Since it might be easier to understand the issue in a synchronous context, I'll create a few examples below that explore this without using promises or observables.

---

#### Consider this Non-Observable Code:

In this first example we have a function `addNumbers` that does the work of adding two numbers for you. It is eager, so it will do the work immediately and then return a value once invoked. You can see that on line 5, `c()` will be equal to 8. `3` and `5` are added together on line 6 then printed on line 8

```ts
function addNumbers(a, b){
  const answer = a + b;
  return () => answer;
}

const c = addNumbers(3, 5);

console.log("This should be an 8:", c());
```

In this next example, we have a very similar function, but it is lazy. It remembers the numbers you gave it but it doesn't actually add the numbers until something invokes it. In this case, `c` needs to be invoked `c()` before the `3` and the `5` are actually used in any way. `5` and `3` are not added together until line 7.

```ts
function addNumbers(a, b){
  return () => a + b;
}

const c = addNumbers(3, 5);

console.log("This should be an 8:", c());
```

#### Lazy vs Eager Consequences

Consider these two examples. If you understand why they print different values, you understand the issues at hand :)

**Example 1:**

```ts
const a = { n: 3 };
const b = { n: 5 };

function addNumbers(v1, v2) {
  const answer = { n: v1.n + v2.n };
  return () => answer;
}

const c = addNumbers(a, b);

a.n = 7;

console.log('Eager Evaluation:', c());
```

Here, `c.n` is equal to `3 + 5` because `c` was evaluated before `a.n` was set to `7`. This is the same as when you retrieved the user before they were deleted. It doesn't see that the user info has changed in the meantime because the value has already been calculated.

**Example 2:**

```ts
const a = { n: 3 };
const b = { n: 5 };

function addNumbers(v1, v2) {
  return () => ({ n: v1.n + v2.n });
}

const c = addNumbers(a, b);

a.n = 7;

console.log('Lazy Evaluation:', c());
```

Here, c.n is equal to `7 + 5` because c was evaluated **after** `a.n` was set to `7`. This is the same as when you retrieved the user using `defer`. This time we check the value of `a.n` the moment that `c()` is evaluated, not when `addNumbers(v1, v2)` is evaluated.

See the difference?

Comment: It looks like option 2 that it did not work for him, what is the different?

Comment: @oz1985oz They would be no different if what you're switching to is an observable. Because it is a promise, `switchMapTo` evaluates the promise right away and switches to the same promise every time. `switchMap` doesn't create the promise until it receives an emission. So it's the same as `switchMapTo` with a `defer` inside **( which is just option 4)**

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer

Comment: So the code that does not work would return the same value forever?? @MrkSef

Comment: @Itay Of course! :)

Comment: @MrkSef You said: "This happens because promises are eager and observable are lazy." But from the rest of your answer it is obvious that this problem has nothing in particular to do with either promises or observables. I suggest you edit the first part.

Comment: @RonInbar How would you edit this? If `this.storageService.getAsync<IUser>('user')` returned an observable instead of a promise, this problem wouldn't arise and `switchMapTo` would be fine. The distinction is between eager and lazy evaluation semantics, but isn't it important to the issue at hand that promises have the former semantics while observables have the latter semantics?

Comment: @MrkSef `getAsync` is a simple function that retrieves a string from `localStorage`. As a matter of fact, I don't even understand why it's asynchronous. To return an observable, it would have to contain *another* function that accesses `localStorage`. *That's* the important difference, not whether it returns a promise or an observable.

Comment: @RonInbar In the context of this question, we can't see what `getAsync` is, but in one of the examples given, Itay writes `await getAsync(...)` which implies that the function returns a promise. Promises, just like observables, contain inner functions. Inner functions alone don't describe evaluation semantics. The eager evaluation `addNumber` above has an inner function that returns the answer too (despite being eager).

Comment: @MrkSef True, but the difference between the two options that work and the two that don't is not in what `getAsync` returns (it's a promise either way) but in when `getAsync` itself is called, and in the first two options (the ones that don't work) it's called immediately by the application code, so RxJS doesn't even get to decide.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MrkSef and Ron Inbar :) I understand now! It is indeed not the Promise or that RxJS that created my problem - it's how I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

Some explanation that helped me couple of times understand `defer`.

Functions composition are executed from inner to outer. First the inner arguments given to the outer function, then the outer function.

```js
function f(x) {
  const result = x * 10;
  console.log("f: ", x, " -> ", result);
  
  return result;
}

function g(x) {
  const result = x + 1;
  console.log("g: ", x, " -> ", result);

  return result;
}

cosnole.log(f(g(2))) 
// g: 2 => 3
// f: 3 => 30
// 30
```

Promises are eager. They do not wait for someone to subscribe.

```js
new Promise(() => console.log("1"));
console.log("2");
1 
2

function f(p) {
  console.log('f:');
}

f(new Promise(() => console.log("1));
// 1
// f:
```

So is the case for `from(somePromise)`:

```js
from(new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log("promise 1");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("promise 2");
    resolve(5);
  });
});

console.log("subscribe - before");

from.pipe(tap(x) => {
  console.log("tap: ", x);
}).subscribe();

console.log("subscribe - after");

// promise 1
// subscribe - before
// subscribe - after
// promise 2
// tap: 5
```

What `from` does behind the scene (simplified):

```js
function from(promise) {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    promise.then(result => {
      subscriber.next(result);
      subscriber.complete();
    }, (err) => subscriber.error(err));
  });
}
```

`from` return an observable that emit when the promise emit, but the promise itself has already started working even before the `from` started and created an observable.

The [defer](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer) operator is for those cases. When the desire is to delay the job and only execute it when someone subscribed.

What `defer` does behind the scene (simplified version):

```js
function defer(workFunction) {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    from(workFunction()).subscribe((result) => {
      subscriber.next(result);
    });
  });
}
```

Only when someone subscribe, the work function is activated.

If we give `defer` to `switchMapTo`, the `switchMapTo` will subscribe to it only when it's source emit.

What `switchMapTo` does behind the scene simplified:

```js
function switchMapTo(workObservable) {
  let lastSubs;

  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    if (lastSubs) {
      lastSubs.unsubscribe();
    }

    lastSubs = workObservable.pipe(
      tap(result => subscriber.next(result)),
    ).subscribe();
  });
}
```